# Browser extension that shows total followers in Twitter search results

Tags: web-browser, twitter

I'm looking for a browser extension (Chrome or Firefox) that displays the total followers of each account that appears in Twitter's search results ([example search)](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=%23example&src=typd).

Currently, you have to mouse-over the profile picture or username in search results one by one for each follower stat to pop-up.  So I'm looking for an extension that displays the follower stats for each tweet directly in the Twitter search results without having to hover over anything.

Is there a browser extension that does this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I created one [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/okcpdamelmfpddfbiheegklhcanmnflp) for you and here you can find the source too: [github](https://github.com/gedro/ExtendedTwitterProfileInformation)

This might not be the best solution but the quickest, I might improve it later.

Comment: Your extension does not work anymore.  Do you have any plans to update it?